# Get movie title dataset from imdb

Tags: dataset, imdb

I want movie title dataset for academic research work. I collected different likes from facebook. I want to filter movie from user's likes. IMDB has a huge movie collection. I download the movie list from http://www.imdb.com/interfaces. But the list is small. Many movies are missing from the list.I downloaded the **movies.list.gz**(24mb). How can I find the complete list of movie title of imdb?

Comment: 24 MB? Are you sure? I just downloaded it from the same place, it stands at 113 MB.

Answer (score 3):

I have used IMDB's datasets for academic research before.

After decompressing **movies.list.gz** you get a file with ~120 MB and 2600000+ movies, which seems like a decent number of films to me, heheh.

Tip: If you're trying to integrate IMDB's data with other movie datasets you might have, download the "aka-titles.list.gz" file too as it contains different variations for movie titles.